# Display last login for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm building into my application the functionality to show when a member was last online, in my SQL query I am doing a `datediff` from when the user last signed in and comparing it to `SYSDATETIME()`.

But unfortunately I do not have the ability to specify a range with in a case statement.  However if I was able to specify a range then it would look like this:

```
 Case DATEDIFF(DAY, p.LastLoggedIn, SYSDATETIME())
  WHEN 0 THEN 'Online Now'
  When >= 1 and <= 7 then 'This Week'  
  When >= 7 and <= 14 then 'Within Two Weeks'
  When >= 14 and <= 21 then 'Within Three Weeks'  
 END
```

I will then take this and display it on the user's profile, would you someone be able to show / help me with the syntax to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
declare @diff int

set @diff =DATEDIFF(DAY, p.LastLoggedIn, SYSDATETIME())

print @diff

select 
 case 
  WHEN @diff=0 THEN 'Online Now'
  When @diff>= 1 and @diff<= 7 then 'This Week'  
  When @diff>= 7 and @diff<= 14 then 'Within Two Weeks'
  When @diff>= 14 and @diff<= 21 then 'Within Three Weeks'  
 END
```